# Correct way of binding Model data to Views and update the latter

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, model-view

I'm working with Python+Qt (PyQt5) for few time and I was wondering what is the most efficient (and correct) way to bind the Model structure (let say a `List` of objects) to a View representation (let say `QListWidgets`) so as to achieve safe and efficient updating of the latter when the former is modified (added/deleted/modified elements).
I was thinking of different strategies, such as:

- Subclassing `List` object to implement a *`on_change`* method in the Model that ask for an update in the View
- Use another type of structure that implement the above
- Just *hard-calling* the View update each time I'm processing Model data updates

Are there any suggestion? I'd like to highlight that "`List[MyObject]` vs. `QWidgetList`" is just the topic I'm currently working on, but my question is meant to be as much general as possible.

## EDIT

Thanks to @BrenBarn and @musicamante I came acress Model/View architecture so that the inheritance of [QAbstractListModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html) helps easily handle the structure data below a `QListView`.
The very only drawback is that each time the model is update (inserting/deletion/editing), a manual emission of `QAbstractListModel.dataChanged` signal is to be performed

Comment: Qt has some of its own classes to handle models.  Have you looked at stuff like [QAbstractListModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html)?

Comment: Thanks @BrenBarn, I didn't know it and I've just had a look. Actually I'm not sure how it could help me in doing this. I mean, ok it is another way of implementing a list, but I can't realize what advantages could come from subclassing it instead of the stardard List in python.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding what you're asking. When dealing with data structures, the [model/view concept of Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) is always used (except from very basic structures like QList): the base is QAbstractItemModel no matter what view is used, as even the higher level views still use an underlying QAbstractItemModel. So, if you need Qt views, unless the data structure is very simple and doesn't require much interaction, a Qt model should always be subclassed. Note that basic models are provided: QAbstractListModel and QAbstractTableModel.

Comment: And for "intermediate" situations, QStandardItemModel could be a fine solution. That said, I still don't understand what exactly is your question, as I'm under the impression that you're asking about a suggestion (which is generally considered off topic on SO). There's no "most efficient", generally, it all depends on your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll go through this abstractions more in detail since, as I said, I'm quite new at Qt. However, you're right, I didn't highlighted the point of my question. It was meant to investigate the best method to track and automatically update the view each time the model changes. I mean, assuming that the very simple list (being it a `QList` or a `QAbstractItemModel` or even a python `list`) is changed from somewhere by adding/removing/modifying some items, how should I efficiently approach the automatic update of the view